# android: NullpointerException on startDrag() after animation

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, nullpointerexception

I have a custom view which is basically a `FrameLayout` with an Imageview and a textview. I used the drag and drop on this view and its working perfectly. Then I perform a `RotateAnimation` on this view. I can move this view once more but the next time i touch the view, it disappears with the following exception:

```
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124): Unable to initiate drag
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.View.startDrag(View.java:16331)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.example.annotations.AnnotationView.onTouchEvent(AnnotationView.java:51)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7392)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2229)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2235)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2177)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1482)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2483)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2125)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7577)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4421)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4399)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4505)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:178)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
03-06 21:18:26.367: E/View(21124):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The following codes to rotate the view are written in the `onProgressChanged()` of a seekbar:

```
                    RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(mCustomView.ROTATION, progress - 180,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    // r.setStartOffset(1000);
                    // r.setDuration(1000);
                    r.setFillAfter(true); // HERE
                    mCustomView.ROTATION = progress - 180;
                    mCustomView.startAnimation(r);
```

`onTouchEvent()` inside the custom `View` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);
        if (data.equals(null))
            Log.d("Nully", "data + " + data.toString());
        if (shadowBuilder.equals(null))
            Log.d("Nully", "shad" + shadowBuilder.toString());
        this.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, this, 0);
        this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

I debugged the app with breakpoints and the object does not seem null in the hit just before this exception.

Comment: Put your questions here, not a link to them.  If you're going to ask for help, don't make people link all over the place.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be easier to view it in pastebin since the stacktrace is huge.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG Friendly tip, the more details the better (code, stacktrace, logs, clear description). People get made and downvote if they need to ask for more info.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG  There is not enough information here to assist you directly.  It's obvious that the object you are trying to reference has somehow died or is in use somewhere else that won't let you touch it.  Look into what is happening with the object to see if it's still alive when you try to move it again.  Do a null check etc...

Comment: @SamusArin I did the null checks on all those parameters. None of them are null.The view itself cant be null, right? cos these codes are inside the onTouchEvent of the view.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG  Make sure that you null checks are in the respective context - event handlers are outside the context of the Activity in which they are defined.  In an example, if you are trying to touch the UI thread from a handler you will receive an NPE.  This sounds like a context issue.

Comment: I've never used dragging, so I don't have any insight into this, but Android Addict is right, it sounds like your object is being destroyed at some point. You may need hook into some overrides and/or catch some events to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You basically need to either `cancel()` the animation or `clearAnimation()` from the View, before you will be able to Drag again. You can trigger this cleanup in the AnimationListener's `onAnimationEnd()`. I went with clearing the animation from the view, because canceling was creating multiple "images" of my view.

Exactly why you need to do this, I don't know.